# PostgreSQL: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: postgresql

У меня есть две таблицы:

```
CREATE TABLE source.staticprompts (
    id              INT,
    projectid       BIGINT,
    scriptid        INT,
    promptnum       INT,
    prompttype      VARCHAR(20),
    inputs          VARCHAR(2000),
    attributes      VARCHAR(2000),
    text            VARCHAR(2000),
    corpuscode      VARCHAR(2000),
    comment         VARCHAR(2000),
    created         TIMESTAMP,
    modified        TIMESTAMP


);


CREATE TABLE target.dim_collect_user_inp_configs (
    collect_project_id      BIGINT NOT NULL,
    prompt_type             VARCHAR(20),
    prompt_input_desc       VARCHAR(3000),
    prompt_input_name       VARCHAR(1000),
    no_of_prompt_count      BIGINT,
    prompt_input_value      VARCHAR(100),
    prompt_input_value_id   BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    script_id               BIGINT,
    corpuscode              VARCHAR(20),
    min_recordings          VARCHAR(2000),
    max_recordings          VARCHAR(2000),
    recordings_count        VARCHAR(2000),
    lease_duration          VARCHAR(2000),
    date_created            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(),
    date_updated            TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    CONSTRAINT must_be_unique UNIQUE (prompt_input_value, collect_project_id)

);
```

Мне нужно скопировать данные из source.staticprompts в target.dim_collect_user_inp_configs таким образом, чтобы в случае, если обнаружили для prompt_input_value уже имеющееся значение, то нужно посмотреть, не изменились ли prompt_input_name и prompt_input_desc и если изменились, то обновить (вместе с датой обновления).

Пробую делать такой запрос:

```
INSERT INTO target.dim_collect_user_inp_configs AS t (
            collect_project_id,
            prompt_type,
            prompt_input_desc,
            prompt_input_name,
            prompt_input_value,
            script_id,
            corpuscode)
        SELECT
            s.projectid,
            s.prompttype,
            el.inputs->>'name' AS name,
            el.inputs->>'desc' AS description,
            jsonb_array_elements(el.inputs->'values') AS value,
            s.scriptid,
            s.corpuscode
        FROM  source.staticprompts AS s,
            jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs::jsonb) el(inputs)
        ON CONFLICT
            (prompt_input_value)
        DO UPDATE SET
            (prompt_input_desc, prompt_input_name, date_updated) =
            (EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc,
            EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name,
            NOW())
        WHERE t.prompt_input_desc != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc
            OR t.prompt_input_name != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name
RETURNING *;
```

Но выдает ошибку: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

не могу понять, что делаю не так.

И по ходу вопрос... Можно ли как-то для RETURNING * вывести просто общее кол-во строк, для которых коснулось изменение? Просто RETURNING count(*) нельзя, так как нельзя использовать аггрегатную функцию здесь.

Comment: ON CONFLICT для работы требует наличия уникального индекса, по которому будет проверяться, обнаружен конфликт или нет. У Вас в структуре есть только композитный уникальный индекс, и его выражение не совпадает с выражением в ON CONFLICT - именно на это и ругается сервер. Ведь вставляемая запись может конфликтовать сразу с несколькими записями - и к какой, спрашивается. прикладывать action?

Comment: Да, я тоже так подумал. Добавил ON CONFLICT(prompt_input_value, collect_project_id), но теперь оно выдает ошибку ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE command cannot affect row a second time Подсказка: Ensure that no rows proposed for insertion within the same command have duplicate constrained values.

Comment: Тоже логично. UPDATE должен быть детерминированным - в т.ч. не зависеть от порядка обработки строк исходных данных. Что в свою очередь требует, чтобы одна и та же строка обновляемой таблицы не обновлялась двумя разными строками таблицы с новыми данными - т.е. строго одно соответствие, либо ни одного. Твои входные данные нарушают это правило. отсюда ошибка.

Comment: И теперь я не понимаю как исправить )

Comment: Это косяк входных данных. И корректировать надо именно их. На таблицу с новыми данными накладывать то же ограничение уникальности, выявлять дублированные записи, и чистить, оставляя только актуальную. В исходных данных это `(jsonb_array_elements(el.inputs->'values', s.projectid), )`. Думаю, стОит слить запрос-источник во временную таблицу (или прямо в запросе - в CTE) да поковыряться там.

Comment: Спасибо! Нужно 7 символов, чтобы написать (

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Решил так:

INSERT INTO target.dim_collect_user_inp_configs AS t (
            collect_project_id,
            prompt_type,
            prompt_input_desc,
            prompt_input_name,
            prompt_input_value,
            script_id,
            corpuscode)
        SELECT s.projectid,
               max(s.prompttype),
               max(el.inputs->>'name') AS name,
               max(el.inputs->>'desc') AS description,
               v.value,
               max(s.scriptid),
               max(s.corpuscode)
        FROM source.staticprompts AS s
           CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(s.inputs::jsonb) AS el(inputs)
           CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(el.inputs->'values') AS v(value)
        GROUP BY s.projectid, v.value
        ON CONFLICT
            (prompt_input_value, collect_project_id)
        DO UPDATE SET
            (prompt_input_desc, prompt_input_name, date_updated) =
            (EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc,
            EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name,
            NOW())
        WHERE t.prompt_input_desc != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_desc
            OR t.prompt_input_name != EXCLUDED.prompt_input_name
RETURNING *;
```